# VB.Net looping through a string

Tags: vb.net, encoding

I have a string say "768932A3" that I want split up into two's like this:
76 89 32 A3 for purposes of conversion to binary. I have tried looping but it doesn't work. Kindly help:

```
For i = 0 To data.Length - 1

    j = i + 2
    incremented &= Convert.ToInt64(data.Substring(i, j), 16)
    ascii &= Chr(Convert.ToInt64(data.Substring(i, j), 16))
    i = j + 2

Next
```

Comment: Careful, now. Chr is using your thread's current ANSI code page. Were that to be different than at the time and place that the string was serialized to a hexadecimal string, you'd be decoding it wrong. (And, your current ANSI codepage is almost certainly not called ASCII so your variable has a misleading name.)  You really must be certain of which encoding was used during serialization and decode that very same encoding. Decoding text is commonly done via a byte array and uses a System.Text.Encoding class. See [Character Encoding in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of Substring is not the ending position but the lenght of characters to consider from the starting position.

```
For i = 0 To data.Length - 1 Step 2
    ' Not clear what are you trying to do here 
    ' incremented &= Convert.ToInt64(data.Substring(i, 2), 16)

    Dim value As Long = Convert.ToInt64(data.Substring(i, 2), 16)


    ascii &= Chr(Convert.ToInt64(data.Substring(i, 2), 16))
Next
```

Comment: I get an error about an unhandled overflow exception

Comment: That doesn't happen with the test string "768932A3". What are the datatypes of the ascii variable and incremented variable?

Comment: I have made the correction and it has worked thanks.